# Linear regression with binary independent variable

Tags: r, linear-regression

I am trying to run a linear regression with a binary independent variable - I am expecting to get 1 estimate comparing those with a value of 1 to those with a value of 0, however, when I run the model I get 2 estimates - 1 for each value of the binary variable? Any thoughts on what I might be doing wrong? (I have checked and my variable is defintily binary coded as 0 and 1)

This works fine when i try it on the mtcars dtaset

```
Call:
lm(formula = mpg ~ factor(vs), data = mtcars)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)  factor(vs)1  
  16.62         7.94
```

... but not in my dataset

```
Call:
lm(formula = bmi_18 ~ factor(art_sc), data = ds)

Coefficients:
  (Intercept)    factor(art_sc)0  factor(art_sc)Yes  
      23.5550            -1.1835            -0.7439
```

Comment: Looks like your `art_sc` variable has 3 unique values: 0, Yes and (I guess) 1. How did you check that your values are only 0 and 1?

Comment: Have you tried `levels(factor(art_sc))` to see the actual levels?

Comment: Can you show the levels of `art_sc`? E.g. `levels(ds$art_sc)`?

Comment: You could try `lm(formula = bmi_18 ~ art_sc == "Yes", data = ds)`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help, looks like my variable does have 3 levels, which is why I was getting strange results. It comes up as binary in STATA which is why i was sure it would be binary in R.

```
 > levels(factor(ds$art_sc))
 [1] ""    "0"   "Yes"
```